# Libgdx BitmapFontGenerator font pixelated

Tags: android, fonts, libgdx

I have an issue with the libgdx ttf font generator. No matter what I try, I get the font pixelated. This is what I have right now that minimizes but makes it still visible:

```
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter;
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;

    parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
    parameter.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;

    generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.ROBOTO_CONDENSED_BOLD));
    parameter.size = Constants.SELECTION_DESCRIPTION_FONT_SIZE;
    parameter.color = Constants.GARAGE_FONT_COLOR;
    generator.scaleForPixelHeight(Constants.SELECTION_DESCRIPTION_FONT_SIZE);
    descriptionFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();
```

Is it possible that the camera I am using is 854x480 per say, but the screen size is 1920x1080 that causes the pixaltion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem does indeed lie within the resolutions. My hud camera was converting to 854 - 600 width range and height accordingly. Having a screen with resolution 1920x1080 makes the font considerably pixelated with spritebatch being set to hud camera with twice the lower resolution.